# How to find one side of a rectangle, if I have other side and slope

Tags: geometry, rectangles

So suppose I have the width of a rectangle that is 1000 cms and its slope that is at 20 degrees. How can I calculate the other length required for the height of this rectangle....

Comment: slope is angle the diagonal makes to a side, right? what is height?

Comment: @Narasimham: Slope is the angle the diagonal makes and height is the left side height of the rectangle

Comment: These type of questions can be easily solved using a branch of mathematics called Trigonometry. [Here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trigonometry.html) is a very nice guide for beginners covering the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Suppose $x$ is the basis of the rectangle and $\alpha$ the slope of the diagonal ( in your case $\alpha=20°$), than the height is $h= x \tan \alpha$ and the area is

$
A= x \times h =x \times x \tan \alpha
$

Here the solution:

> $x^2=\dfrac{A}{\tan \alpha}=\dfrac{1000}{\tan (20°)}=2747 \Rightarrow x=\sqrt{2747}=52.42$

Comment: Sorry for being so dense(I do not come from math background at all) Can you tell me what x tan α means? In other words is there a formula to calculate the tan?

Comment: You can see here for a definition of trigonometric functions : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent.  For the values of $tan (20°)$ you can use a calculator, or see here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%20(20°)%3D